# Seamlessly UV Unwrap Unique Shapes

Tags: texturing, uv

I am fairly new to Blender, however I understand 3D concepts quite well, minus a few specific situations. This is one of those situations I am stumped by. Basically I am creating a modular hill, that uses one corner piece rotated around its origin point to create the hill. In 2D space, the corner piece more resembles a triangular shape with 3 sides rather than the ideal 4 sided plane used in UV Mapping. This causes a limitation, as textures are seamless horizontally and vertically, but never diagonally. When the shape is unwrapped to a UV Mapping, due to the triangular shape, it attempts to map it diagonally rather than vertically or horizontally. I am aware that this is difficult to understand from my explanation, as it was difficult to really explain, so I have attached a photo with a visual representation. I have a bit of a deadline, so please upvote if you are unable to answer the question, so that someone who understands the task can help. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Found the solution here: https://blenderartists.org/t/uv-unwrapping-unique-shapes-seamlessly/1517531 Had to edit the texture in a photo editing program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example I created a plane with standard UV Unwrap, subdivided by 2, and modeled into desired shape rotating 2nd vertical edge loop by 30 degrees, third by 60, fourth by 90, then snapped into place (I used a shape key for better clarity).

Remember to uncheck the "Correct Face Attributes" Option during edit.

[image]

Then added another subdivision level for avoiding severe stretching and scaled the new edge loops for more roundness.

Hope it can help.

[image]

Comment: This is actually a better solution than I found! Multiple ways to skin a cat I suppose. So I got half this correct originally, but i had horrible stretching and all I had to do was subdivide again. haha smh. Thank you!

Comment: Where is your origin point as you rotate the edge loops? I am getting strange result when performing the rotation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it. I missed the part about snapping the edges into place.

Comment: Sorry. I feel clueless. I did the UV Unwrap before making changes and as I make the changes it updates the UV! Is there a way I can keep the original unmapping or do I have to change it in the UV editor manually.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.